# Notice: Undefined index php $_request

Tags: php, html

I need eliminate this warning with an if sentence
I tried to use if **$_REQUEST['fname']** 
but it not worked. I'm new in PHP

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
Name: <input type="text" name="fname">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<?php 
if($_REQUEST['fname']){
 $name = $_REQUEST['fname']; 
 echo $name; 
}
?>

</body>
<html>
```

Browser

Notice: Undefined index: fname in /var/www/php_functions.php on line 11

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply check this by [**isset(**)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Try this code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['fname'])){
 $name = $_REQUEST['fname']; 
 echo $name; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks friend. I didn't remember the isset fuction

Comment: Welcome. You can check it for [empty()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) also.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the `REQUEST` array you have to use! It's POST since your method of the form is post:

like this:

```
$_POST['fname']
```

And i think you want to check if it is set like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['fname']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `$_REQUEST` variable also contains `$_POST`. But the way you are checking it is incorrect.

It can be done using `isset()` to check its existence:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['fname'])){
    $name = $_REQUEST['fname']; 
    echo $name; 
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php